# Is knowledge of the meaning of the word “ubiquity” ubiquitously considered to be ubiquitous?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, common-word

*Please pardon the pun.*

I was in a conversation on a game’s online chat, talking about how common an item was, and used the word “ubiquitous” to describe it. But, much to my surprise, the point of contention for one user was not my assertion, but my use of the word “ubiquitous”.

In the words of this user (censorship mine):

> the word ubiquity in place of, say, “how common it is” is being assh**ish and pedantic

I’ve always used the word in natural speech, and it’s not one I consider to be overly “advance”, yet this user insisted that the only reason to use it would be to “seem intelligent”.

**Question:**
I do agree there are some words that are somewhat uncommon, or outdated. And that these words might elicit a response implying that their usage is “just for show” (not that I’d agree with one). But is “ubiquitous” one of them?

**Notes:**

- The context was in a game’s chat, and the average age of a user that
  was present would be around 20. I’d like to know if the word is
  commonly known *in general*, but noting if the fact it was a casual
  environment affected the validity of the user’s clam would be
  appreciated.
- The user’s response was arguably immature, and how vehemently they
  argued their point might have to do with their anger, as opposed to
  actually supporting their own stance, but I’d like answers to ignore
  this.
- This user referred to [reference.com’s difficulty index on the
  word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ubiquity?s=t), which
  claims “Few English speakers likely know this word”. While my
  experience with the word might not be indicative of all people, I
  know most people to understand it, and use it. Additionally, I
  couldn’t find a source on how that index is calculated, so it might
  be the opinion of an editor.

Comment: Personal opinion: I would *not* expect a random person I selected from the population of native English speakers to know what "*ubiquitous*" means. I *would* expect a random person selected from the population of regular contributors to EL&U to know what "*ubiquitous*" means. Suggestion: try googling "ubiquitous" and "everywhere", and compare the orders of magnitudes of the total numbers of pages containing the two words.

Comment: @DanBron - I would! Quotidian, no. Ubiquitous, absolutely. And (to AT) if anyone called you an asshole for using the word, they were exhibiting volumes more about themselves than about you.

Comment: @Medica You would expect a random 18 year old from Idaho to know the definition of "ubiquitous"?

Comment: @medica Your faith in humanity uplifts me.

Comment: @DanBron - I have a good reason to have some degree of faith in humanity, I think. But I don't think it's naive.

Comment: My advice: stay away from people who taking the use of unfamiliar words [as disrespect](http://www.youtube.com/v/P51vKeHjHr4).

Comment: @medica, Sorry if I came across as sarcastic. I was being sincere. I think too cynicism and pessimism is too wide-spread, and am happy to meet a fellow spirit.

Comment: @Malvolio That's solid advice. In my opinion, even if the word is generally considered pretentious, the user's behavior was uncalled for.  Unfortunately some people treat anonymous communication as a "free pass" to act out.

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix - your link doesn't take me to the site you described. Could you possibly check the link and edit?

Comment: @medica on another computer the link worked for me, but just in case people didn't feel like scanning the page I included the relevant part in the question (the claim "Few English speakers likely know this word")

Comment: Ah, thank you! That surprises me. I tried some of the most obscure words I know, and some of them came in lower than ubiquitous, which I believe is fairly common.

Comment: @DanBron I used your suggestion and posted the results as an answer

Answer (score 1):

@DanBron had an excellent suggestion,to "compare the orders of magnitudes of the total numbers of pages containing [two words]". I recall having seen this used as a metric before.

I've searched for the words "ubiquitous","omnipresent", and "pervasive" and got the following:
[image]
[image]

As the charts show:

- The overall differences are rather small, they're all within one
  order of magnitude.
- The difference between the number of mentions of "ubiquitous" and
  "omnipresent" is relatively small. I'd expect that because I
  personally find "ubiquitous" and "omnipresent" to be more
  interchangeable than "ubiquitous" and "pervasive" (I feel pervasive
  has a slightly different meaning).
- The difference between mentions of "ubiquitous" and "pervasive" is
  the largest, probably because of the greater difference in meaning.

**Note:** @DanBron's original comment suggests the word "everywhere" as an example. I didn't include in the chart because there are many cases for which "everywhere" fits, but "ubiquitous" usually does not (e.g. when it starts a sentence). In my specific case, it's meaning would have been somewhat obscure (but it wasn't a common case).

I got 39,200,000 results, a difference of 1 order of magnitude from "ubiquitous", but inspection of just the first page shows many examples of uses of "everywhere" that "ubiquitous" cannot replace (I'm also comparing the adjective form of a word to an adverb)

That being said, "everywhere" can be seen as a kind of measuring stick. The most common adverb according to a list derived from "The Corpus of Contemporary American English" is "up", which by comparison gives 3,790,000,000 results. This is 2 orders of magnitude above "everything", and 1 above "ubiquitous".

The numbers are graphed as such:

[image]
[image]

Seeing as how dwarfed both "everywhere" and "ubiquitous" are by "up" (when made to fit in this post, a linearly scaled bar graph only shows "up"), it doesn't seem too far-fetched that a large number of people would know the meaning of "ubiquitous". However, it's clear this method of comparison is not without it's defects, so I encourage others to provide more insight into this question.

Comment: Also, forgive the typo that is forever immortalized in that image of my chart :(

Comment: The typo, unfortunately, also skews the results (assuming the numbers correspond to the words as typed). Also, I'm getting dramatically different results than you are; compare, for example, [the ngram for "ubiquitous" vs "omnipresent" vs "everywhere"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ubiquitous%2C+omnipresent%2C+everywhere). Even if we just look at the last two decades, *everywhere* is two orders of magnitude more common than *ubiquitous*, and that's in books, which are a more formal context, where rarer, more niche words are used more frequently than in everyday conversation.

Comment: @Dan Bron The typo wasn't in the search results, I only made the mistake in creating the graph. Additionally, the results you got in that ngram seem to be in line with the ones I got, with "everywhere" being 1 order of magnitude more common than "ubiquitous" in 2008. And I attributed that difference to being related to the fact "everywhere" and "ubiquitous" are not always interchangeable ("everything" can be used in most cases of using "ubiquitous", but the reverse isn't true) in the question.